# Is this Liverpool accent? "I wanna hold your hand"

Tags: pronunciation, accent

I like this song "[I wanna hold your hand](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipADNlW7yBM)" by The Beatles.

Paul and John sing the phrase "I wanna hold your hand"
as "I wanna hol'-your hand".

Other cover singers sing it as "I wanna hol d-your hand"

"I wanna hol'-your hand" is Liverpool or England accent?
Please tell me, thank you.

Comment: I hear them singing *I wanna hol d-your* and sometimes even *I wanna hold your*. Pronunciation differs in the same song. I don't think you are hearing the **d** in *I wanna hol d-your*.

Comment: I'd be careful about trying to understand dialects and pronunciation based on what you think you hear in a song. In music, it's quite common for syllables, sounds, and words to get slurred together in the vocals. The end result might be a mondegreen – there is an interesting article about those [here](http://www.newyorker.com/science/maria-konnikova/science-misheard-lyrics-mondegreens), and some particularly humorous misheard lyrics are cataloged [here](http://www.kissthisguy.com/).

Comment: I hear it as *I wanna hold your hand*. Quite normal, in my humble opinion.

Comment: I think he elides /d/ in this song (I just let YouTube play The Beatles' until I heard one!): [I Saw Her Standing There](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=wLNQ8EfTiJs#t=72). "And we hel(d) each other tight."

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Damkerng T. One more question, OK? Does Paul tend to elide /d/ sound or do Englishmen tend to elide /d/ sound?

Comment: You really should find examples in **speech** to ask a question like that. (There are [plenty of examples](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beatles+interview), after all.) Many singers elide sounds like that, no matter where they are from.

Comment: In addition, accents tend to even out when singing, especially vowel sounds  See, for example,, [Why you put on an American accent when you sing](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/music/rockandpopmusic/11720137/Why-you-put-on-an-American-accent-when-you-sing.html) and [Why British Singers Lose Their Accents When Singing](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2013/08/why-british-singers-lose-their-accent-when-singing/). For the longest time I didn't know that singer [Keith Urban](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Urban) was not an American.

Comment: [Why Don't You Hear Someone's Accent in a Song?](http://mentalfloss.com/article/29780/why-dont-you-hear-someones-accent-song) is really good.

Comment: The Beatles do retain enough *English pronunciation* in their singing, though, that I can definitely tell they're not from the USA.

Comment: I really appreciate all your comments, and thank all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I summarize all comments.

1, I can't hear "d" sound of Paul's "hold your hand" that natives can.

2, Another native says he elides "d" sound.

3, It's not dialect.

Thank you all for your cooperation.

p.s. I can hear the "d" sound in these covers.

https://youtu.be/YB--EqJFkvE?t=19

https://youtu.be/VqfdoWDzVfc?t=20

Clearly different from The Beatles'.
That's why I thought it's dialect or something.

Thank you again.

Comment: if you have something, please comment. I wonder why.

Comment: It may just be the particular recording you posted in your question (which is blocked where I am currently). Dropping **d**'s is not necessarily characteristic of a **Scouse** accent. In this live recording [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46_yYR6tGOI) The Beatles clearly pronounce the **d**. Caitlin Hart is American and she clearly enunciates, notice how she sings **please**. McFly are from the London area where plain speech is less **sing-song** than in the North.